# Add Woocommerce Title to link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a simple link on single Woocommerce product pages and I need to add the title of the current product page to the link as a parameter so I have;

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com/movie-samples/sample?name=MOVIENAME" >ORDER A SAMPLE</a>';
```

How do I replace MOVIENAME with the title of the current product page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = get_the_title();
echo '<a href="http://example.com/movie-samples/sample?name=' . $title . '" >ORDER A SAMPLE</a>';
```